# How to connect my template to admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, layout, adminhtml, template

If there are several errors, please specify all. Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <RunwaySale_Merchandiser>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </RunwaySale_Merchandiser>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <merch>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>RunwaySale_Merchandiser</module>
                        <frontName>merch</frontName>
                    </args>
                </merch>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <admin1112>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>RunwaySale_Merchandiser</module>
                        <frontName>admin1112</frontName>
                    </args>
                </admin1112>
            </routers>
        </admin>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <merch>
                    <class>RunwaySale_Merchandiser_Block</class>
                </merch>
                <adminhtml>
                    <rewrite>
                        <catalog_category_tree>RunwaySale_Merchandiser_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Tree</catalog_category_tree>
                    </rewrite>
                </adminhtml>
            </blocks>
            <helpers>
                <runwaysalemerchandiser>
                    <class>RunwaySale_Merchandiser_Helper</class>
                </runwaysalemerchandiser>
            </helpers>
        </global>
        <adminhtml>
            <menu>
                <runwaysalemerchandiser module="runwaysalemerchandiser">
                    <title>runwaysalemerchandiser</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>admin1112/adminhtml_merch</action>
                </runwaysalemerchandiser>
            </menu>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <merch>
                        <file>runwaysale.xml</file>
                    </merch>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </adminhtml>
    </config>
```

> controllers/Adminhtml/MerchController.php

```
class RunwaySale_Merchandiser_Adminhtml_MerchController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/runwaysale.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <admin1112_merch_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="merch/adminhtml" name="runwaysale" template="index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </admin1112_merch_index>
    </layout>
```

Path template:

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/runwaysale/index.phtml

Comment: please try <block type="merch/adminhtml" name="runwaysale" template="runwaysale/index.phtml" /> in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/runwaysale.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the folder on runwaysale.xml

change this lign from

```
<block type="merch/adminhtml" name="runwaysale" template="index.phtml" />
```

to

```
<block type="merch/adminhtml" name="runwaysale" template="runwaysale/index.phtml" />
```

On template field you have to use the folder, without the folder **runwaysale** magento will try to find the file **index.phtml** on **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/** and not on **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/runwaysale/**

Remember to clean the cache after this changes.

I hope this helps you

Comment: thanks , but this don't working :(

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <admin1112_merch_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="merch/adminhtml" name="runwaysale" template="index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </admin1112_merch_index>
    </layout>

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think that your Admin link its not correct, you should use something like this:

```
<adminhtml>
            <menu>
                <runwaysalemerchandiser module="runwaysalemerchandiser">
                    <title>runwaysalemerchandiser</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/admin1112</action>
                </runwaysalemerchandiser>
            </menu>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <merchandiser>
                        <file>runwaysale.xml</file>
                    </merchandiser>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </adminhtml>
```

And on your layout you are using type="merch/adminhtml" to run the admin page but merch is defined only to frontend...